# Edit a different page in WP Customizer

Tags: ajax, theme-customizer

I'm working with Customizer's incredible options, and so far so good, it's really powerful and does everything I want. However, I'd like to extend it, so instead of editing only the main page, I want to allow editing of inner pages.

While I achieved this (saving the changes and navigating to the edited page), I can't make it work in live Customizer. I mean, even if I navigate to that page inside Customizer, it isn't grabbing the live changes at all. I've added the JS bind for live preview so that isn't the problem (plus, it works if I save, it just doesn't show in LIVE mode). Is there a way to achieve this, or is it just that live Customizer works only for the main page?

Another related question: I have these inner page sections apart of the main page section. Is it possible to make the preview window load the page I want to edit when I click the accordion tab for that section? I'm thinking that maybe that's the issue. Just to be clear:

site title, background, header, etc ----> main page in preview window
portfolio items ----> load portfolio page in preview window
store items ----> load store page in preview window

Any help appreciated, I was searching on Google and here, but couldn't find anything so far.

Comment: I have added a link to admin bar in order to load the page I want to edit, like this: http://www.domain.com/dashboard/customize.php?url=/store/products/ to see if this helps in any way, but nevertheless, it loads the main page, so I'm totally lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Customizer will apply its changes into the frame over the entire site. Try it yourself with Twenty Thirteen and see. Make some changes, and without saving, navigate to a single post or single page and see how the changes persist even without saving.

So likely you're doing something else that breaks that functionality in some way. In which case the question isn't so much how to make it work as it is to find what you're doing to break it, and stop doing that.

Comment: yes Otto, after playing with it for more time I achieved it, however don't remember what was wrong because I just tried different things until it worked. Either way, my main concern was the 2nd part (loading a certain page directly) which I achieved by adding a link on admin bar